# Android HTML5 app flickers when softkeyboard comes up

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app for iPhone and android using **HTML5**, **Jquery mobile 1.2** and **Phonegap 2.1.0**. On login page when user taps on input field the softkeyboard comes up and the page slides up with a flickering effect. Same app works fine on iPhone. The problem is only on Android mobile.

I tried - **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**, it stops the flickering but again the softkeyboard covers the submit button, and i am not able to scroll page while the keyboard is visible. In native app this is achieved by wrapping the content into . But for HTML5 app I am not able to fix this. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set - setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) with your WebView